# Updating Input type number in React Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update the input value. It's working fine, it's updating its value. However, there is a problem, when it's updated its value, it's converting to string from number. I have already tried with **Number**, **parseInt**, it does not work. it always converts to string.

```
import React from 'react';
import useForm from '../lib/useForm';

const CreateProduct = () => {
  const { input, handleChange } = useForm({
    name: 'mama',
    price: 0,
  });
  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="price">
        Price
        <input
          type="number"
          id="price"
          name="price"
          placeholder="Price"
          value={parseInt(input.price)}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CreateProduct;
```

and here in the custom function:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function useForm(initialValue = {}) {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState(initialValue);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [name]: value,
    });
  }
  return {
    input,
    handleChange,
  };
}
```

and here is the initial state:
[image]

and here is the updated state with the number gotcha
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

Inputs deal only in strings. If you want the value to be anything other than you should convert it when passing to the handler, or in the handler itself.

## Solution

Convert the value back to a number when processing in handler

```
function handleChange(event) {
  const { name, type, value } = event.target;

  setInput(input => {
    const nextInput = {...input}

    switch(type) {
      case 'number':
        nextInput[name] = Number(value);
        break;

      // handle other input type cases

      default:
        nextInput[name] = value;
    }
    return nextInput;
  });
}
```

[image: Edit updating-input-type-number-in-react-form]

Comment: what if the input passed in is ```name```  not ```price```?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 Ah, good catch. Guess OP will need to handle the numerical fields separately.

Comment: It's work, however, there is more input field like string, then problem arise NaN,
```

Comment: @MamunurRashid You are exactly right. I amended my solution to use a "reducer" type pattern to check the input's `type` attribute and handle the state update accordingly. Apologies for initially misunderstanding your full issue.

Answer (score 0):

This check whether `name` 's type is `number` or not. When it is number, parse it to `Number` type to prevent it be converted to `string`. If not, just update the input by what it is originally pass in.

```
setInput({
      ...input,
      [name]: typeof name === 'number' ? Number(value) : value,
});
```

Comment: Input is not an only string, there is more input like string, then NaN is a problem

Comment: Updated the answer. Btw, just see your comment in below answer. When creating product, some checking can be done. Eg. can prevent there should be some input

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: @AmitVerma Good point, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing it that way?

```
   setInput({
      ...input,
      [name]: name === "price" ? parseInt(value) : value,
});
```

Comment: if there is no input, there is a NaN problem again